# Как реализовать такой скрипт на jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Как с помощью jquery при нажатии на элемент выезжает контент? И как это можно реализовать? Так же еще есть смена контента в зависимости от нажатой кнопки. Как, например, это реализовано на сайте https://charmerstudio.com/ru (см. раздел с проектами). Изобразил все на gif. Спасибо за внимание. Знаю, что нужно использовать hash(), но как добалять в url id/data-src элемента я не знаю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тут мало кто переходит по незнакомым ссылкам. 
Выкладывайте gif.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто ради спортивного интереса. Изначально вопрос был один и ранее добавленный ответ считался принятым. Но ровно до тех пор, пока вопрос кардинально не изменился, после чего собственно ответ и перестал считаться быть принятым. Спекуляция, однако :)

```js
$(".menu a")
  .mouseover(function() {
    $("div [data-id='" + $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "") + "']").delay("200").fadeIn("500");
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    $("div [data-id]").hide();
  });

$(".menu a")
  .click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-tab'),
      content = $('.content[data-tab="' + id + '"]');
    $(".content [data-tab='" + $(this).attr('data-tab').replace("#", "") + "']");
    $('.menu a').addClass('menu__li__opacity').removeClass('menu__li__active');
    $(this).addClass('menu__li__active');
    $('.content').hide();
    content.delay('500').slideDown("slow");
    $('.img').addClass('img__close');
    $('.wrp__img').addClass('wrp__img__passive');
    $('.wrp__text').addClass('wrp__text__active');
  });

$('.close_up').click(function() {
  $('.menu a').removeClass('menu__li__opacity').removeClass('menu__li__active');
  $(this).removeClass('menu__li__active');
  $('.content').hide();
  $('.img').removeClass('img__close');
  $('.wrp__img').removeClass('wrp__img__passive');
  $('.wrp__text').removeClass('wrp__text__active');
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.menu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu li {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.menu:hover li a {
  opacity: 0.2;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.menu li a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu__li__active {
  color: red !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  zoom: 1.2;
}

.menu__li__opacity {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.img {
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -200px;
  margin-left: -300px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.wrp__img div {
  display: none
}

.wrp__img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.wrp__img__passive {
  width: 50%;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.wrp__text {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.wrp__text__active {
  width: 50%;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.wrp__text p {
  color: black;
}

.content {
  display: none;
  padding: 50px;
}

.content__active {
  display: block;
}

.content h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.content img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.img__close {
  display: none !important;
}

.close_up {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 40px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: gray;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}

.wrp__text:hover .close_up {
  opacity: 1;
}

.close_up:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

.close_up::before,
.close_up::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -1px;
  background: white;
}

.close_up::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.close_up::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrp__img">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a data-tab="1" href="#item-1">Раз</a></li>
      <li><a data-tab="2" href="#item-2">Два</a></li>
      <li><a data-tab="3" href="#item-3">Три</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="img" data-id="item-1">
      <img src="https://www.salakfilozof.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/arabesk-sarkilar.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="img" data-id="item-2">
      <img src="https://www.altkia.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/753f93209d86058cb21da037ad2df212.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="img" data-id="item-3">
      <img src="https://www.lider-press.by/images/articles/2018/February/raznoe/Colorful.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrp__text">
    <div class="content" data-tab="1">
      <h2>Раз</h2><img src="https://www.salakfilozof.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/arabesk-sarkilar.jpg"></div>
    <div class="content" data-tab="2">
      <h2>Два</h2><img src="https://www.altkia.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/753f93209d86058cb21da037ad2df212.jpg"></div>
    <div class="content" data-tab="3">
      <h2>Три</h2><img src="https://www.lider-press.by/images/articles/2018/February/raznoe/Colorful.jpg"></div>
    <div class="close_up"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы лучший. Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 6):

Ну вот как-то так. Стиль, анимация и прочее уже по желанию.

p.s. Добавил стиль и анимацию. Так все же интереснее.

```js
$(".menu a")
  .mouseover(function() {
    $("div [data-id='" + $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "") + "']").delay("200").fadeIn("500");
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    $("div [data-id]").hide();
  });
```

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.menu {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.menu li {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.menu:hover li a {
  opacity: 0.2;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.menu li a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.content {
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -200px;
  margin-left: -300px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.wrapper div {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content" data-id="item-1">
    <img src="https://www.salakfilozof.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/arabesk-sarkilar.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="content" data-id="item-2">
    <img src="https://www.altkia.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/753f93209d86058cb21da037ad2df212.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="content" data-id="item-3">
    <img src="https://www.lider-press.by/images/articles/2018/February/raznoe/Colorful.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#item-1">Раз</a></li>
  <li><a href="#item-2">Два</a></li>
  <li><a href="#item-3">Три</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ты можешь это сделать просто на `jQuery`.

Добавь к атрибут к элементу ссылки. Допустим `data-src=""` равный фоновой картинки. И при наведении мыши меняй background у твоего блока с картинкой на картинку которая содержится в `data-src`.

Эфекты смены картинки добавить по вкусу)